# Python Pandas mapping a column but writing to another column in case of exception

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframe "df":

```
 A | B | Notes

"asd" | 1 |  

"vsd" | 1 |

"jgy" | 1 |
```

I'm creating another column "C" by mapping the column "A" as follows:

```
df["C"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: foo(x))
```

But in some cases the foo function throws an exception. I am currently writing this exception in the same column i.e "C".

Is it possible to write this exception in "Notes" column whenever there is an exception in the foo function in the mapping code.

And also, if I'm mapping more than one columns (not all at once), is it possible to append these exceptions in Notes column

For eg:

if foo("asd") throws an exception I want the dataframe to be:

```
A | B | Notes

"asd" | 1 | ExceptionTypeA  

"vsd" | 1 |

"jgy" | 1 |
```

But if I apply another function on column B and it throws an exception, I want the dataframe to be:

```
A | B | Notes

"asd" | 1 | ExceptionTypeA, ExceptionTypeB  

"vsd" | 1 |

"jgy" | 1 |
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just write the logic directly into the `foo` function?

Comment: The problem is that `foo` function is mapping one column to another column. There is no way for me to write in `Notes` column with this logic.